# What's the proper way to ask for new answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

So I have a question that is very relevant...and has been [asked before](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/752/what-ebook-readers-work-well-with-roleplaying-pdf).

This question was asked all the way back in the prehistory of today's technology - 2010.  Most of the answer acknowledge that things may change in the future.

I don't want to ask an exact duplicate of the question - it would be pointless.  But I don't know a good way to direct attention to the question and get questions that aren't so out-of-date.

Honestly, I feel the question maybe isn't such a great fit for StackExchange, where duplicate questions are seriously frowned upon but the relevant question's answers are very time-localized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to add a bounty to the old question soliciting new answers.

That said, that even though these kinds of questions are frowned upon across the network, they have traditionally done fairly well here because we ask that answers be based on experience and expertise rather than just opinion. And there are fairly objective and narrow *experiential* criteria for evaluating these answers (how do gaming PDFs look, does it run the apps you need to play effectively, etc).

I'd go ahead and put some rep on it with a blurb soliciting updates and answers based on current tech.

Comment: Looking at that specific question, perhaps an answer should be made into a community wiki?  It's unlikely any one individual will have sufficient experience to provide a comprehensive answer -- for instance, I can talk about how well my Nexus 7 works, but can't contrast it with other devices.

Comment: @starwed perhaps a new, unified CW answer that takes the best of all the existing answers and is kept up to date with new ones would be good. It's the kind of thing CW is meant for.